# Exporting SQL table to Excel in C# is randomly picking cells formats for dates

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, office-interop

I am trying to export an SQL Dataset to an excel document.

At certain points when outputting the date fields the excel cells are being formatted at certain points as date cells and some as general.
This is causing the dates to display sometime in the format that I want, UK style day/month/year, in the American style month/day/year.

If it was just one way that would be fine because the report would be at least consistent. However the fact that the code will sometime output the correct format and sometimes won't is very annoying

My code so far:

```
private void doReport(DataSet myDS)
    {
Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        int i;

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Report produced on the " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Project Type";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "Client";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 3] = "Date Started";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 4] = "Target Date";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 5] = "Date Completed";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 6] = "Stage Target";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 7] = "Stage";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 8] = "Assigned To";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 9] = "Notes";

        i = 4;

        foreach (DataRow row in myDS.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = row["strProjectDescription"];
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = row["strClient"];
            DateTime dteProjStart = (DateTime)row["dteProjectStart"];
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 3] = dteProjStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            DateTime dteProjTarget = (DateTime)row["dteProjectTarget"];
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 4] = dteProjTarget.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            if (rbViewProjectsCompletedVal.Checked)
            { 
                DateTime dteProjFin = (DateTime)row["dteProjectFinished"];
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 5] = dteProjFin.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            }
            if (row.IsNull("dteProjectStageTarget") == false)
            {
                DateTime dteProjStageTar = (DateTime)row["dteProjectStageTarget"];
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 6] = dteProjStageTar.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            }
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 7] = row["strProjectStageDescription"];
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 8] = row["initials"];
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 9] = csSQL.runSQL("select strProjectNotes from tbl_AdminSupport_Projects where intASProjectID = " + row["intASProjectID"], "Management").Tables[0].Rows[0]["strProjectNotes"];

            i++;
        }


        xlWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
        xlWorkSheet.Rows.AutoFit();
        xlApp.Visible = true;

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Dataset structure:

Any item prefixed with str is a nvarchar(max), dte is a date

Comment: Your own code is storing *strings* in the cells instead of the actual DateTime values

Comment: Except when the report is finalised some of the cells have been formatted as 'Date' cells and the rest are displaying the date American style. The rest of the cells are formatted as general as showing the date in UK style. I want the information outputted as strings in the UK format. Somewhere along the line its being changed back to a date format in excel.

Comment: I seem to recall that Excel will use the values in the first x rows to decide the data type for the column so if the first x rows contain `null` in a particular column it will probably use General. Since you are outputting in "dd/MM/yyyy" format I'd guess that those are General and the US date format ones are being interpreted as dates. I found this issue when outputting to a CSV then opening it with Excel. Since you are interfacing via the Excel Interop, why don't you type your output, rather than using string for everything?

Comment: @MattBartlett there's no "date format". There's the value and how it's formatted for display. That's controlled by the *style* of the cell, which your code doesn't set. This means that Excel will try to guess what the text in that cell is. If it can be displayed as a date, it will be displayed as a date using *the end user's locale*. If not, it's treated as text

Comment: @MattBartlett start by storing DateTime values so Excel doesn't have to guess. Then set the cell style to the one you want.

Comment: @MattBartlett an even better idea would be to use [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Reading-and-Writing-Data) or a similar library to create a real `xlsx` file without installing Excel and using Office Interop. Loading the data could be as easy as `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(myDS.Tables[0])`